# Qual a melhor proporção para eu criar este dataset?

Tags: dataset

Estou criando uma 'convolutional neural network' para detectar imagens NSFW(Not safe for work) ou 18+. Mas eu não sei a proporção e tamanho do meu dataset. Espero juntar cerca de 70.000 imagens com 50% sfw e 50% nsfw. No qual irei treinar a rede com 50.000 imagens e valida-la com 20.000.

Qual a melhor proporção para eu criar este dataset?